# How to analyze jmeter reports ,any open source reporting framework available which helps in analyzing reports after test run?

Tags: jmeter

How to analyze  jmeter reports ,any open source reporting framework available which helps in analyzing reports after test run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is [SmartMeter.io](http://www.smartmeter.io) which is build upon JMeter. It generates reports automatically after the test or it can generate the report additionally even from JMeter results. Read more in this [blog post](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/smartmeter-load-test-report).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Source:

   - [JMeter Result Analysis Plugin](https://github.com/afranken/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin)
   - [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/)
2. Web-based:

   - [JAnalyser](http://janalyser.com/)
   - [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/)
3. Standalone:

   - Custom Listeners from [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/) project
   - [Suggestions and Recipes for Log Analysis](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/LogAnalysis)

Comment: Dmitri, is JAnalyser available? I can't find information about it. Blazemeter and SmartMeter.io are really expensive for my company!